# Jquery - CS:GO betting site error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Hello everyone**

I am running into an issue where when I click on withdraw and verify my re-captcha afterwards it gives me this error:

```
Javascript error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at Object.parse (native) at Object.success (http://blur/template/js/offers.js?v=106:249:17) at j (http://blur/template/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1:27244) at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://blur/template/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1:28057) at x (http://blur/template/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1:85993) at XMLHttpRequest.b (http://blur/template/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1:90047)
```

So I had been looking and this is my code:

```js
$.ajax({
  "url":url,
  dataType: 'json',
  success:function(data){
   try{
    console.log("Testing purposes: " + data);
    console.log("URL:" + url + g);
    //data = JSON.parse(data);
    if(data.success){
     console.log(data);
     $("#left .reals").empty();
     $("#right .reals").empty();
     $("#right .bricks").removeClass("hidden");
     $("#avail").html(formatNum(data.balance));
     var count = data.items.length;
     var eleA = [];
     for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
      var item = data.items[i];
      var url = IMG.format(item.img,110,50);
      
      


      

      

      var price_class = "ball-1";
      if(DEPOSIT){
       price_class = "ball-0";
      }

      var slot_class = "";
      var price_content = item.price;      
      
      if(price_content==0){
       price_content = item.reject;
       slot_class = "reject";
      }else{
       price_content = formatNum(price_content);
      }      
       
      bot = 0;
      if(item.botid){
       bot = item.botid;
      }
      var botLabel = "";
      if(!DEPOSIT){
       botLabel = "Bot "+bot;
      }

      var ele = DIV.format(
        item.name,i,item.price,bot,
        item.name,i,item.price,bot,item.assetid,url,
        item.name,
        price_class,price_content,
        slot_class,botLabel,item.view);
      eleA.push(ele);
     }
     $("#left_number").html(count);
     document.getElementById("left").getElementsByClassName("reals")[0].innerHTML = eleA.join('');

     addPadding("#left",6);
     
     if(data.fromcache){
      inlineAlert("success","Loaded "+count+" available items from cache - <a href=\"javascript:loadLeft('nocache')\">force reload</a>");
     }else{
      inlineAlert("success","Loaded "+count+" available items.");
     }        
    }else{
     inlineAlert("error",data.error);
     if(data.count>0){
      cmd();
     }
    }
    if(data.tid){
     showPending(data);
    }
   }catch(err){
    inlineAlert("error","Javascript error: "+err.stack);
    console.log(err);
    console.log(url);
   }
  },
  error:function(err){
   inlineAlert("error","AJAX error: "+err.statusText + "<br />" + err.stack);
  },
 });
}
```

EDIT: I made it so that it doesnt have to parse to JSON. Added "dataType: 'json'," before the success:function.. 
But instead of a whole bunch of errors, it gives me AJAX Error: OK. So I added err.stack and it says "undefined".. 
**EDIT2: Updated the code that I'm currently having now, only error it gives is AJAX Error now which says : OK (undefined)..**

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the response from the ajax call before calling `data = JSON.parse(data);`? Is it possible that the response you're getting is invalid JSON?

Comment: Ya, error means you are trying to parse invalid formated JSON data

Comment: Tried it, it gives out nothing.

Comment: This is the full code. [link]http://www.csgohexagon.net/template/js/offers.js?v=106

Comment: I have been trying for 1 or 2 month(s) now.. haha, thats the funny part.. Might even be such a simple mistake. :P

Comment: First, when answer to something in comments, add "@saduskO", where instead of your name put the one you are replying to. Second, can you show us the content of '/get_bank_safe?g-recaptcha-response=' this URL when logged in. The not logged in version of the JSON is ok.

Comment: More over, you shall narrow down you're code if possible so it's easier for people to answer.

Comment: @MasterDJon On your last comment you said "Narrow down your code", I did this but I only made it wide to have an small overview of what I'm exactly writing, also I used `console.log("URL:" + url + g);` and this is what came out of that.

URL:/get_bank_safe?g-recaptcha-response=03AHJ_VushMHi1a0b5oPW-_StloOD7H7QaeICC517AuubcLiPpVYOCRdFsxvQemlmEUz2zc-x9rJRYPE-y7HpZj6L ... blablabla, it continues but can't write too big of comments. Thanks by the way for helping as well.

Comment: When I said 'the content', I meant what is returned when calling the URL, not to URL itself. (Edit your question and put it there)

Comment: @MasterDJon the content of the website itself? To load the inventory of the bot. What the URL gives when I get on the URL is just blank.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a protection before calling data = JSON.parse(data), look if its an empty string.

Because trying this :

```
JSON.parse("")
```

gives me this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input(…)
```

Comment: I edited the script, I edited the question as well with the new code.

Comment: Well, you just moved the problem in another place, but it is the same reason. What you got is an empty string.